# Fail to deploy rails app on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, azure

I'm trying to deploy my Rails 4 app on Azure VM running Ubuntu 14.04.
Here's a logfile, atomic fails to install. ruby-v gives me ruby 2.0.0p451

Any ideas how to fix that?

```
   azureuser@my-url:~$ sudo gem install atomic
    Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
    ERROR:  Error installing atomic:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

            /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
    /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from extconf.rb:13:in `<main>'


    Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/atomic-1.1.15 for inspection.
    Results logged to /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/atomic-1.1.15/ext/gem_make.out
    azureuser@my-url:~$ ruby -v
    ruby 2.0.0p451 (2014-02-24 revision 45167) [x86_64-linux]
```

Comment: I would caution you using `14.04` since it is not yet released. I believe it is still in `Beta1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your gems are using ruby1.9.1 and you are missing dev files.

So install that using this command

```
sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.1-dev
```

If you are not sure about your ruby version you can use this command

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you also have the `build-essential` package installed. You can check using `dpkg -l | grep build-essential` or simply run `sudo apt-get install build-essential`.

Personally I tried lots of things before realizing I was missing the above mentioned package.